# SQLite in memory unit testing show "no such table error" instead of real error message

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, nhibernate

I have a simple `NHibernate` based application that I'm unit testing it with in memory `SQLite`. Whenever the test fails, for example because of duplicate entity, the unit test fails with error 'there is no such table TABLE_NAME' error instead of showing original error.

If I switch to real file database, all tests (passed or failed) are evaluated correctly. How this is possible at all and how can I correct this?

Answer (score 3):

this is often caused by not using SchemaExport with the inmemory database. Sqlite inmemory databases are dependend on the connection, so each connection has its own database.

```
new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true); // creates database, fill it and throws away
```

instead of

```
using (var session = sessionfactory.OpenSession())
{
    new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false, session.Connection, null);

    // use session in test
}
```

Comment: I'm using Sharp Arch., where should I put this?

Comment: new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false, session.Connection, null); should be just before running the test case with the session the test case uses. How to get the config from Sharparch i don't know

Comment: The one sentence in your answer, "Sqlite inmemory databases are ... so each connection has its own database" was an "A-Ha" moment for me. Thanks!